# \linewidth plus \cline plus centering using tabularx does not work out

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularx, cline, hline

I am trying to create a table using tabularx to stretch a table to over the full page width. Usually, it would not need the full width but I like it better if it's like this. In my table, I have some multirow cells, therefore I use `\cline{2-9}` instead of \hline at some points. Finally, I would like to have the content of my cells centered. However, I seem to be unable to combine all these aspects.

If I use `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{llXXXXXXX} %\textwidth or \linewith leads to the same result` stretching works but centering of the cell values does not as can be seen in this example
[image]

If I try `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{llccccccc}` centering works but the something is off with the \cline's and \hline's
[image]

Condensed code:

```
\begin{table}[H]    
\centering
\begin{threeparttable} %because I'm using footnotes
\caption{some caption}
\label{tab:some table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{llccccccc}
\toprule
 &    &\multicolumn{7}{c}{some ID} \\
 &    &1   &2   &3   &4  &5   &6   &7   \\ \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{This is} &a test &$\sim$   &2   &+   &+   &+   &+   &+   \\ \cline{2-9}
                         &not a test    &+   &10   &+   &+   &+   &+   &--   \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

Can anybody help me fix this? This would be great!

PS: I posted this question also on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/g6j3i9/linewith_cline_and_centering_columns_using/) but haven't received an answer yet. If a working solution is found there, I'll let you know.

Comment: next time consider adding a  [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are four ways to do the table.

First and foremost: you *have* to specify at least an `X` column in `tabularx`. But you don't really need it, as table 2 shows.

On the other hand, `\multirow` adds nothing to clarity, rather the converse, see table 3 (where also the left and right paddings are removed).

I'd simply use the natural width, unless the final size is not so different from the global text width.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,multirow,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{The table with \texttt{tabularx}}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX*{7}{c}}
\toprule
 &    &\multicolumn{7}{c}{some ID} \\
 &    &1   &2   &3   &4  &5   &6   &7   \\ \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{This is} &a test &$\sim$   &2   &+   &+   &+   &+   &+   \\ \cmidrule{2-9}
                         &not a test    &+   &10   &+   &+   &+   &+   &--   \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

\caption{The table with \texttt{tabular*}}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}\hspace{\tabcolsep}}
  ll
  >{$}c<{$}
  @{\extracolsep{0pt}\hspace{2\tabcolsep}}
  *{6}{>{$}c<{$}}
}
\toprule
 &    &\multicolumn{7}{c}{some ID} \\
 &    &1   &2   &3   &4  &5   &6   &7   \\ \midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{This is} & a test     & \sim &  2 & + & + & + &+ & + \\
\cmidrule{2-9}
                         & not a test & +    & 10 & + & + & + &+ & - \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\bigskip

\caption{The table with \texttt{tabular*} and no \texttt{\string\multirow}}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  ll
  >{$}c<{$}
  @{\extracolsep{0pt}\hspace{2\tabcolsep}}
  *{6}{>{$}c<{$}}
  @{}
}
\toprule
 &    &\multicolumn{7}{c}{some ID} \\
\cmidrule(l){3-9}
 &    &1   &2   &3   &4  &5   &6   &7   \\ \midrule
This is & a test     & \sim &  2 & + & + & + &+ & + \\
\cmidrule(l){2-9}
        & not a test & +    & 10 & + & + & + &+ & - \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\bigskip

\caption{The table as I would do}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  ll
  *{7}{>{$}c<{$}}
  @{}
}
\toprule
 &    &\multicolumn{7}{c}{some ID} \\
\cmidrule(l){3-9}
 &    &1   &2   &3   &4  &5   &6   &7   \\ \midrule
This is & a test     & \sim &  2 & + & + & + &+ & + \\
\cmidrule(l){2-9}
        & not a test & +    & 10 & + & + & + &+ & - \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for extensive help! I haven't figured out yet which version I want to use but all of them work great!

Answer (score 0):

As was in the meantime suggested in the comment, I added the following column type

```
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
```

so that the content is centered.
I then changed the `ccccccc` columns with `*{7}{Z}` (syntax to define 7 consecutive columns of `Z` type).

I also added the `\otoprule` separator so that you can have the same line thickness of `\toprule` but equal spacing between the rows for the headings:

```
\newcommand{\otoprule}{\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]}
```

A MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand{\otoprule}{\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]} 

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable} %because I'm using footnotes
        \caption{some caption}
        \label{tab:sometable}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ll*{7}{Z}}
            \toprule
                                     &            & \multicolumn{7}{c}{some ID} \\
                                     &            & 1                              & 2  & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7   \\ \midrule
            \multirow{2}{*}{This is} & a test     & $\sim$                         & 2  & + & + & + & + & +   \\ \cline{2-9}
                                     & not a test & +                              & 10 & + & + & + & + & --   \\ \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]